# How to include the content of a decimal variable inside the body of email sent from my iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email

I have read some posts regarding the MFMailViewController , and wonder if I can include the content of a decimal variable, which I am using in my Iphone app to store result of some calculation, into the body of the email message which to be sent from my iPhone app.

Here is the code for the calculation I am using inside my app to calculate and display the result into a Text field in the screen:

```
GPM1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: GPMinput1.text];
GPM2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: GPMinput2.text];
Result = [GPM1 decimalNumberByDividingBy:GPM2] ;
GPMresult.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:Result];
```

I want to display the content of the "Result" decimal variable as part of the email body. For example: Your GPM result = "Result".

Any body has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 float GPM1 = [GPMinput1.text floatValue];
 float GPM2 = [GPMinput2.text floatValue]];
 float Result = GPM1/GPM2 ;

MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString    *pResult=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"GPM result  = %.4f",Result];
[controller setMessageBody: pResult isHTML:NO];         
[controller setSubject:@"Subject"];         
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];      
[controller release]
```

Comment: Thank you, but shows " GPM result = 0.000 " in the email body, while it should show " GPM result = 6.1234 " where 6.1234 is the content of the decimal variable "Result". It seems the pResult variable in your code could not read the decimal value in Result. Can you please advice other working alternative ?

Comment: Also just to mention that I am declaring Result as NSDecimalNumber object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the MFMailComposeViewController on iOS 3.0 and later and implement the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
if(controller) {
  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
[controller release];
```

When The user sent the mail, you get called back with the following method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
  if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
    NSLog(@"It has been sent.");
  }
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @ckurse Thank you for your reply, I am looking for a more specific answer to the specific case I have mentioned in my question (to include content of some variable I am using in my app to be part of the email body to be sent, for example if the variable "Result" I mentioned earlier in my question has the value of 6.12345, then I want the body of the email to be something like: " GPM result = 6.12345".  Any idea how to do that with MFMailComposeController ?